# Trying to make encryption program - unknown error

Tags: python

I've been coding an encrypt and decrypt program for fun, and have come across and error that i have never seen before just wondering if anyone could help out?

if parent.winfo_viewable():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'winfo_viewable'

Comment: welcome to SO @TFMarchent43 it is always better add the code you are working on, It will be easy to solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry i have just worked out the problem thanks though, will do for next time!